# Use Bash for Irssi

Tags: bash, irssi

Alright I am writing a shell script to open Irssi and then automatically connect to freenode. Should I edit the file at ~/.irssi/config or is there a way to simulate me typing /connect irc.freenode.net? I have used echo, send, and expect but it hasn't worked. Here is the code I have so far.

```
irssi
echo "/connect irc.freenode.net"
```

Comment: Have you tried with just this?

irssi -c irc.freenode.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

irssi provides a `-c` switch which allows you to specify a server to connect to when the application starts. From [irssi's man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/irssi):

```
-c, --connect=SERVER
    connects to SERVER
```

So, you could just use either one of these:

```
$ irssi -c irc.freenode.net
$ irssi --connect=irc.freenode.net
$ irssi --connect irc.freenode.net
```

The reason why `echo` does not work is because it is not connected to irssi's standard input. Basically, what happens is:

- You start irssi, connect to a server, have a little chat, leave.
- Once irssi is closed (its process terminates), then your `echo` text will be printed.

You will have the same result if you use:

```
$ irssi ; echo "Hello"
```

Now, as far as `expect` is concerned, this is probably due to the fact that irssi is a ncurses-based client. Since ncurses redefines the way input and output are manipulated, it is very likely that `expect` cannot communicate with the process anyway. Additionally, there is nothing to expect on `stdout` specifically, since irssi sends many things on that stream:

- A blue header.
- A few blank lines, some with text if you used `-c` (connection log).
- Another blue line with some text in it.
- A prompt.
- ...

And not just:

```
[(status)] _
```

To which you could respond with:

```
/connect irc.freenode.net
```